# Hangfire recurring job

Tags: hangfire

i have the following scenario:

i have 2 hangfire server instances serverA and serverB connecting to the same hangfire DB.

serverA adds a recurring job to a queue called "recurring", which is being picked up by serverB to execute, I dont want serverB to execute the recurring job, is this be design?

When i instantiate serverB, i explicitly initialized the "QueueNames" property to NOT include "recurring", but serverB still seems to pick this job up?

Am i missing something here? any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Maybe "recurring" is not the safest name to choose :)

Comment: Can you please post your code? That helps to suggest you what is going wrong